# SSRS matrix report and dynamic column

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

i want to develop a matrix report in SSRS. my data in table looks like

```
ToTalSale  RemanSale  DiagSale   TotalCall   CountryCode
---------  --------- --------    ---------   -----------
 16500       11200      2500        5              GB
 12300       10100      1500        7              US
```

the above data is stored in my table and now i want to show data like

```
Fields             GB         US
-----------------------------------
TotalSale       16500        12300

RemanSale       11200        10100

DiagSale        2500         1500

TotalCall          5            7
```

i want to show field data vertically and country code horizontally.
so guide me how to have the above output with SSRS matrix report.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Try to make your matrix manually not by wizard. and keep your field at right hand side and in one column type column names as it is. In cyrstal report I've done it . I'm sure ti will be done in SSRS also. This is not a big deal.

```
                                          Or
```

You can pivot your query and do the same.